# How to make <td> on click to be editable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on my homework and I can't figure out how can I make the table row to be editable on a click. For example, on click 'John' I can modify the name. The code below is just a small part of the code, just to get a clue of how the table is created. Any hint or solution is appreciated.

[image]

```js
        // Creating Table and Display DATA
        let tableBody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        let ShowID = document.createElement('td');
        let ShowName = document.createElement('td');
        let ShowSurname = document.createElement('td');
        let ShowAge = document.createElement('td');
        let ShowPosition = document.createElement('td');
        let ShowYofExperience = document.createElement('td');
        let ShowEducation = document.createElement('td');
        let ShowStatus = document.createElement('td');
        let ShowNote = document.createElement('td');

        for(let i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++){
            let currentCandidate = candidates[i];
            ShowID.innerText = currentCandidate.id;
            ShowName.innerText = currentCandidate.name;
            ShowSurname.innerText = currentCandidate.surname;
            ShowAge.innerText = currentCandidate.age;
            ShowPosition.innerText = currentCandidate.position;
            ShowYofExperience.innerText = currentCandidate.experience;
            ShowEducation.innerText = currentCandidate.education;
            ShowStatus.innerText = currentCandidate.status;
            ShowNote.innerText = currentCandidate.note;
        }
        // Checkbox 
        let ShowCheck = document.createElement('input');
        ShowCheck.type = 'checkbox'
        ShowCheck.id = 'checked';
        ShowCheck.value = 'true';

        tr.appendChild(ShowCheck);
        tr.appendChild(ShowID);
        tr.appendChild(btnPreview);
        tr.appendChild(ShowName);
        tr.appendChild(ShowSurname);
        tr.appendChild(ShowAge);
        tr.appendChild(ShowPosition);
        tr.appendChild(ShowYofExperience);
        tr.appendChild(ShowEducation);
        tr.appendChild(ShowStatus);
        tr.appendChild(ShowNote);
        tr.appendChild(btnDelete);
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        let divShow = document.getElementById('content');
        divShow.style.display = 'block'; // display table
        clearForm(); // Clear Form Inputs
```

```html
    <div id="content" style = 'display:none;'>
        <div id="results">
            <table id = 'table' class = 'dnone'>
                <tr>
                    <td>#</td>
                    <td>Candidate ID</td>
                    <td>Preview Candidate</td>
                    <td>Candidate Name</td>
                    <td>Candidate Surname</td>
                    <td>Candidate Age</td>
                    <td>Candidate Position</td>
                    <td>Candidate Years of Exp.</td>
                    <td>Candidate Education</td>
                    <td>Candidate Status</td>
                    <td>Candidate Note</td>
                    <td>Delete Record</td>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button id = 'btnDeleteAll'>Delete All</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: hi joe, please show what have you tried?

Comment: You can try adding the `contentEditable` attribute on on `td` in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can make it editable, specifically I'll touch on two ways, one is using the attribute `contentEditable` and the second one is rendering an input.

---

### Two possible solutions

1. You can use `contentEditable` attribute inside a `div`. Here's an example of how that works:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable>I'm editable</div>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>I'm not editable</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

2. You can Add `<input>` to `<td>` when it is clicked and change `<input>` to  when it is blurred.

I'll share an example of the code, for simplicity sake we will not render the input using `document.createElement` but have it on each td, you can also do it and render the input manually every time.

```js
function onTdClick() {
  document.querySelector('.my-span').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.my-input').style.display = 'block';
}

function onInputBlur() {
  document.querySelector('.my-span').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('.my-input').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.my-input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="my-span" onclick="onTdClick()">I'm editable</span>
        <input type="text" class="my-input" onblur="onInputBlur()" />
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

---

### Which solution to choose, `contentEditable` or input replacement?

You might be wondering which solution to choose, here are few things to keep in mind:

1. A standard input element is limited to plain text input. using the `contentEditable` attribute allows users to write content that can include formatting, tables, images, etc.
2. Using `contentEditable` isn't as full-proof as it might look on a first glance. Articles from the [Medium Engineering](https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480) team and also the [CKEditor team](https://ckeditor.com/blog/ContentEditable-The-Good-the-Bad-and-the-Ugly/) came out and bluntly said that the `contentEditable` feature is terrible.

With that being said it's important to note that they are building extremely complex WYSIWYG editors that include a lot of complicated features, a lot of the problems they're experiencing with the `contentEditable` feature is when working with more complicated features and not very simple ones.

However there are many things ones should be aware of when using `contentEditable` even with 'simpler' features, this is why a lot of people recommend not using it in most cases.

---

### Bottom Line

Unless you need the user to edit content, use the input/textarea solution. It's much easier to do as `contentEditable` gets complicated pretty quickly.